# How can I detect duplicate values while a program is running?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been writing this code to generate 9 million random numbers which contain 9 digits.

```
import random
passfile=open("C:/Users/HP/Desktop/testfile.txt", "a")
for passkey in range(1,9000000):
    passkey=random.randint(100000000,1000000000)
print(passkey)
passfile.close()
```

How can I passively check for duplicates and delete them?

Comment: This line -> `passkey=random.randint(100000000,1000000000)` what is random here ?

Comment: @ChristianDean `passkey=random.randint(100000000,1000000000)` this line will always make passkey = 100000000 . Doesn't look random right.

Comment: @RajanChauhan Ah, I see we were not on the same page. When you said _"what is random"_ I thought you were asking what the variable name `random` referred to. But you were asking a rhetorically question about how his code could generate a random number.

Comment: @ChristianDean Exactly! Your initial reply was cute though. :D

Comment: On Python 2 `range` returns a list, will use a lot of memory. Use `xrange` if you must (there are probably better ways though.)

Comment: @StefanPochmann Thanks for pointing out. Time has come to change my glasses.

Answer (score -4):

You can use a set to memorise earlier random numbers and print only if elements doesn't exist in the list and then add the number to the list for next.

Comment: This would be extremely inefficient.

Comment: Not only that @Mitch, but this is a very common dupe. Pritam, Please avoid answering common duplicate questions. It avoids having answers spread out all over the network.

Comment: @ChristianDean It's actually not a dupe considering its a file and not a list

Comment: @exali It is though, because the point of the question is entirely the same.

Comment: @Mitch Can you then type out the exact code you would use for this problem? I'm a rookie so I don't understand how can I implement the question in my program.

Comment: @Mitch Exactly. In both questions the objective is to generate a list of random numbers. Regardless of extra details like having to write them to a file, use them in a GUI, etc.

Comment: @Mitch can you suggest a better solution without memorising the previous values please.

Comment: The best answer IMHO is the top answer on the suggested duplicate, which is reason enough for this question to be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @PritamPan see **`unique_everseen`** in the [**`itertools`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) [recipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes). It uses a [**`set`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set).